# DropdownList autoposback after client confirmation

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, onchange, autopostback

I have a dropdownlist with the autopostback set to true. I want the
user to confirm if they really want to change the value,
which on post back fires a server side event (selectedindexchanged).

I have tried adding an onchange attribute "return confirm('Please click OK to change. Otherwise click CANCEL?';") but it will not postback regardless of the confirm
result and the value in the list does not revert back if cancel
selected.

When I remove the onchange attribute from the DropdownList tag, the page does postback. It does not when the onchange attribute is added. Do I still need to wire the event handler (I'm on C# .Net 2.0 ).

Any leads will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried to set the onChange event to a javascript function and then inside the function display the javascript alert and utilize the __doPostback function if it passes?

i.e.

```
   
drpControl.Attributes("onChange") = "DisplayConfirmation();"

function DisplayConfirmation() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')) {
    __doPostback('drpControl','');
  }
}
```

Comment: this solution worked. I liked it because it was the simplest of all. Never had thought that I would need to call __doPostBack(().
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can utilize the the CustomValidator control to "validate" dropdown by calling a javascript function in which you do the confirm():

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="TestDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true"
            ValidationGroup="Group1"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="TestDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="One" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Two" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            function ConfirmDropDownValueChange(source, arguments) {
                arguments.IsValid = confirm("Are you sure?");
            }
        </script>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="ConfirmDropDownValidator" runat="server"
            ClientValidationFunction="ConfirmDropDownValueChange" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Group1"  />
```

Comment: I think that this is the best solution I've seen, and after much searching it's the first time I've seen it, I don't know why more people don't suggest it.

Comment: The best available answer.

Answer (score 6):

The following works when the DropDownList is triggering partial postbacks:

```
// caching selected value at the time the control is clicked
MyDropDownList.Attributes.Add(
    "onclick",
    "this.currentvalue = this.value;");

// if the user chooses not to continue then restoring cached value and aborting by returning false
MyDropDownList.Attributes.Add(
    "onchange",
    "if (!confirm('Do you want to continue?')) {this.value = this.currentvalue; return false};");
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're always returning the result of the `confirm()`, so even if it returns `true`, you'll still stop execution of the event before the postback can fire. Your `onchange` should `return false;` only when the `confirm()` does, too, like this:

```
if (!confirm('Please click OK to change. Otherwise click CANCEL?')) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the onchange attribute will not work if you have have AutoPostBack set to true because ASP.NET will always append the following to the end of your onchange script:

```
;setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'YourDropDown\',\'\')', 0)
```

If you set AutoPostBack to false, then overriding onchange with a "confirm and __doPostBack"  type script (see above, err.. below) will work but you may have to manually create the __doPostBack function.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!confirm('Please click OK to change. Otherwise click CANCEL?')) return false;
```

Always returns so dropdownlist's OnSelectedIndexChanged event fires whether user clicks OK or CANCEL.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your event is wired:

```
dropDown.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dropDown_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

You can also apply a client-side attribute to return the confirmation. Set the index accordingly if cancelled.

```
dropDown.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript: return confirm('confirmation msg')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
&lt;asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlShailendra"  AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlShailendra_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="javascript: { if(confirm('Click ok to prevent post back, Cancel to make a postback'))return true;} " &gt;
          &lt;asp:ListItem Text="tes" Value="1" >&lt;/asp:ListItem&gt;
            &lt;asp:ListItem Text="test" Value="-1"&gt;&lt;/asp:ListItem&gt;
            &lt;/asp:DropDownList&gt;
```

Write the function inline and dont have a "return" for the condition in which you want a post back. This works and is as per the standards.