# Execute javascript confirm on drop down list onSelectedIndexChanged Event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, confirm, selectedindexchanged

I have a drop down list and I would like to invoke a javascript confirm box on the selectedindexchanged event of the drop down list. The problem is I don't know how to invoke the javascript confirm box before the execution of the C# code of the selectedindexchanged event is executed. My .aspx code is:

```
 OnSelectedIndexChanged ="ddlCauses_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

I would like to do something like:

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to change the cause code?');"



OnSelectedIndexChanged ="ddlCauses_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

However I don't think I can assign the onSelectedIndexChanged to two different things...How can I allow for the javascript confirm to be executed and then the C# code executed if yes is selected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DropdownList autoposback after client confirmation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73748/dropdownlist-autoposback-after-client-confirmation)

Comment: It is almost the same, however when the user hits the YES button, I would like for the onSelectedIndexChanged code to be triggered. Instead it does nothing but change the drop down list...Any help on how to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use jQuery you could do the following:

```
$("#yourSelectId").change(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //This makes the standard event not happen
    if(confirm('text'))
        //do something...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly

On the server side you would populate your dropdown and setup the event handler

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            uiItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
            uiItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("One", "One"));
            uiItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("Two", "Two"));
            uiItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("Three", "Three"));
            uiItems.Attributes.Add("onChange", "confirmfunction();");
        }
    }

    protected void ddlCauses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uiText.Text = uiItems.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

On the aspx page you would have

```
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="uiItems" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCauses_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmfunction() {
        if (confirm("Make this change?")) {
            __doPostBack('uiItems', '');
        } 
    }
</script>
```

The caveat to this being that the original value of the select box isn't restored if you choose "Cancel" on the confirm prompt.

Comment: Currently I am  using: 
onChange = "DisplayConfirmation();"   
OnSelectedIndexChanged ="ddlCauses_SelectedIndexChanged"
However, when I hit cancel on the confirm box, it executes the C# code that I have under the ddlCauses_SelectedIndexChanged method. If I hit yes it does a postback but nothing happens. I would like for the reverse to happen, that is, when user hits YES then code in selectedIndexChanged is executed and when user hits NO then nothing happens (just a postback will do)

Comment: I was actually reviewing the code and saw that I just needed to change something in the javascript function. I had: 
<script type="text/javascript">
   function DisplayConfirmation() {
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to change the cause code?')) {
                        __doPostback('ddlCauses', '');}
                    }
</script>

I placed a "!" in the if statement to make it do the reverse. You guys are inspirational :D

Comment: I copied the code exactly and it never performs a postback